# GAE Cloud SQL Charges for lightweight Wordpress install

Tags: sql, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm running a very rough lightweight Wordpress install at http://tbrander1.appspot.com I get at best a few hits a day.

My cloud SQL instance seems to be getting treated as running 24x7 useage (d0 instance) or $10+ per month even though it is set to per use.. What gives??.. is Wordpress itself keeping it active? I have batcache and the GAE plug-in installed which is supposed to minimize any SQL hits...

Is there something I can do to get the charges ie get it running per use?

Seems this will be a Barrier/issue for many WP users if they try using GAE

Comment: It is a configuration issue I believe, that manifests itself in weird billing

Comment: Oh, ok. If you've confirmed that your SQL instance is actually running 24x7, I would reword this question to remove all billing-related aspects, and focus on the instance running when it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you have a scheduled task to run the wp-cron.php endpoint. The default for this is every [2 hours](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/blob/master/cron.yaml). This likely means you are starting your Cloud SQL database qyite frequently. Please bear in mind usage is billed by hour, so if your instance is used at all in a given hour then the whole hour is charged for.

If your app has very little usage try reducing or removing the cron frequency.

Comment: Giving this a try,(hope it works) moved the chron from 2 hrs to 24.. I also updated the GAE plug-in to 1.5 and the WP to 4.0,, we'll see... what is the chron set to do that hits the sql db (curious)? The DB gets backed up every 24 hrs,, which I guess has nothing to do with the chron job..

Comment: I think that may be it! No accruals for several days.. So for now you get the points. Thanks  for the suggestion I'll try to encourage Google to adjust the project docs to make this clearer...

Answer (score 1):

If you set it to on demand it will only connect when its needed. After a few minutes it will shut down again. There will be a spool up time for the first person but it should be very short.

Comment: But that is what I have done but it does not seem to be "spinning down"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/cloud-sdk Go down to 'Editing an instance' if the --activation-policy ALWAYS was set then it won't spool down. This is needed for some jobs (ie event_scheduler)

Comment: I checked the SQL console and Activation is set to on demand and the billing is set to per use..

Comment: Go here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta3/instances/get#try-it and fill out the information. under fields select only 'settings' click execute and scroll down. Look for 'activationPolicy' and see whats set

Comment: "pricingPlan": "PER_USE",
  "replicationType": "SYNCHRONOUS",
  "activationPolicy": "ON_DEMAND",
  "ipConfiguration": {
   "enabled": false,
   "authorizedNetworks":

Comment: Ok, On the overview screen, select Active Connections and Read/Write. Are there periods where its 0?

Comment: Read/Write extended periods of 0 activity (days) don't see Active connections? But "Summary" under app engine shows extended periods of 0..

Comment: Try clicking on the restart button. It will stay off until there is a new connection. If it kicks on right away then something is calling it. https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/instances#restarting

Comment: found active connections it stays at 1, I restarted sql since activity is rw/sec.. it rarely rounds above 0 after restart it seems to be staying at 0

Comment: Sounds like something was connecting to it. Maybe a wordpress setting? I don't know wordpress at all.

Comment: following http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ so you suggest that WP should not maintain connection, that connections should drop to zero? Would not think connection would keep instance up, with no activity?

Comment: I don't know wordpress, but so long as there is a connection the instance will be up and you will be charged. So you need to figure out if you want to keep the connection alive for better performance but costlier or only connect when you need it.

Comment: I'l open a new question more focussed on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Issue raised here on Github https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/issues/31